# Line plot with R with categorical data

Tags: r, plot, linechart

I have a dataset with variables;

subject, group, gender, pretest, posttest, FU_6_month, FU_12_month

```
Subject Group   Gender  Pretest         Posttest        FU_6_month      FU_12_month
1   2   2   118.826601098386    93.7242226833558    45.9022982619128    87.5922938477103
2   2   2   61.076151378316     37.4269190073656    74.0550780537479    125.065288560879
3   2   2   57.5102273980161    77.8629614597533    75.57281055525      47.6327188844442
4   2   2   70.7363734703855    9.66991124269437    89.3449482258492    108.293657994293
5   2   2   9.86907880058945    -10.3608782428914   -37.5688442618089   -75.0331616314858
6   2   2   64.5157954624921    16.5509079527419    41.8441716919839    62.281296652626
7   2   2   63.2566934190156    55.7464724092843    19.0693261189747    59.9351530137349
8   2   2   109.093548562172    31.718921929317     39.6937442573627    52.4519409887752
9   2   2   140.693405017245    140.524720621573    77.5230524280486    134.207295832318
10  2   2   93.9426980661475    46.8332604054467    38.402855719624     50.9079427718743
11  2   2   43.7680225594388    80.6379240148244    96.3606811119212    67.1279194045236
12  2   2   20.1458211058956    -7.04822262983657   8.49333465622865    36.5967882860063
13  2   2   83.469391668149     123.969188001105    106.499980159661    29.6135142560297
14  2   2   96.6687732166198    41.1420718195119    54.7799026008967    56.4261716602755
15  2   2   106.358591131724    144.971834214664    148.026658720866    108.002672122947
16  2   2   16.9581371937412    83.1518225974514    88.0186516925204    121.061427265927
17  2   2   64.2539971694514    63.2117086017753    111.907210080775    37.9182814935607
18  2   2   124.11372018163     118.866157749789    78.6115825756602    39.7082848460843
19  2   2   46.4606560117358    74.4717571331671    40.7418447935371    51.528282732026
20  2   2   114.930656954671    87.3716921095551    71.2297039530053    52.3204838525396
21  2   2   40.4201124083124    86.7274803995984    40.0452102666523    106.294559268573
22  2   2   108.836792961519    55.3938284037392    42.5591569465982    -8.19305292316011
23  2   2   62.3804870892384    73.4711868487922    18.9401981024593    79.1316020496406
24  2   2   34.4038057814076    -10.3210731558527   59.0035259778318    70.0935426080846
25  2   2   90.8027274469837    63.9607510682       23.409456737791     -22.875864241026
26  2   2   11.7507972703742    -2.94630158894237   -58.3073936001535   -11.60312518279
27  2   2   44.80814276417      -14.5096265325743   44.6692531748914    15.2279416937636
28  2   2   50.1321942804589    21.3103925056834    23.4817359003739    4.6942563521538
29  2   2   100.916457384715    79.7904457154806    77.4563447056773    133.933576514761
30  2   2   91.9666694946805    87.5772982344139    74.7225424155036    112.423696361253
31  2   2   88.9334732523178    34.7022650208145    90.5109779763575    74.5346146636566
32  1   1   81.1214937447534    54.1044255781282    84.7921094855582    91.1960453420743
33  1   1   58.8576595772853    43.7588455451153    -28.3737936572789   20.5323873036915
34  1   1   94.7206052432539    117.417745760142    123.549594722528    123.577410999177
35  1   1   35.6759882761208    83.438460147486     101.374418533548    117.407858069453
36  1   1   27.0663967490866    65.1316276924752    40.6863523256917    43.0770501617226
37  1   1   25.8514744435283    65.6129973657268    91.2683460107141    87.8754543146423
38  1   1   38.1949952702174    86.6308464921296    46.3924788350823    75.9032186102214
39  1   1   86.8606779979669    108.826238059586    75.6851380593086    65.4200604841805
40  1   1   -6.27591849716471   37.6110556707935    17.073836159682     2.31274071895368
41  1   1   46.3301324308731    48.8945996406574    28.184935352875     75.0552601606531
42  1   1   75.5207821136948    64.3563772132469    47.0692943366087    6.73314670916386
43  1   1   72.2546738033818    69.586398745141     114.381364281594    111.826984877306
44  1   1   63.4781658850011    99.049067888915     147.435368194586    95.7697872432145
45  1   1   98.7816404692531    119.771236619925    86.0608732865149    63.5925334927907
46  1   1   57.7861680881831    60.9242563489794    115.323242983005    107.812892523927
47  1   1   20.7553750494804    64.2153119771138    80.4530077140549    109.82827909681
48  1   1   120.216467968489    98.1714936196362    103.684406597264    70.9607067374422
49  1   1   79.185403297875     64.5546197197006    25.8163919150245    25.7390824767794
50  1   1   76.7014603032583    76.4261333376855    47.8550073318326    60.1294421424394
51  1   1   28.0279022207291    65.3928762213151    47.0842042316292    87.1936301446947
52  1   1   144.744160722781    87.2810292839688    116.354612596006    107.648295676686
53  1   1   6.33304664550448    28.6180442534099    35.0924364855403    43.4180796117138
54  1   1   61.3353319617994    84.5449868274988    50.4807390973971    66.2394686330681
55  1   1   76.2997829598239    63.5136443275288    121.943272892608    91.1928686386778
56  1   1   92.1450972853901    114.609600784086    76.7511596303626    100.375073126256
57  1   1   28.804633600014     59.8400454024583    72.5911681616019    26.0906198483795
58  1   1   106.980948059764    96.5451150496155    84.9934401810607    74.8203628162023
59  1   1   59.452124962385     89.3319279228802    10.0195199176193    54.346248526172
60  1   1   95.0552085815196    97.2000344846879    70.705403830194     51.3011761075761
61  1   1   61.8002496990622    86.9070024010344    48.3554607420459    85.9692920560173
62  1   1   51.4264598967651    8.55667676146555    20.2154240800391    7.43739168375134
63  1   1   85.4912848778254    85.5693976898857    129.597738684151    91.7808811747717
64  1   1   98.0252031110864    57.6910927029629    75.4148963448406    23.2566349717607
65  1   1   71.7048653453729    78.995107581382     53.2810320681918    62.9720582710283
66  1   1   76.78555002899      69.9939478859649    128.789596038478    83.9802882230193
67  1   1   115.006897750398    129.469936599525    122.703355191477    84.5780155932675
68  1   1   134.540121180658    60.2690032596209    58.0334397473465    77.2650708277708
69  1   1   55.0188905000887    28.8950163475678    29.6744156495995    54.4603122787989
70  1   1   23.0424913085507    36.5297451319085    21.9128320910716    89.0993730787044
71  1   1   84.9353877886003    52.9391040508769    40.5060745487472    97.5747666694516
72  1   1   31.3080252805222    33.2934269506026    40.8168172306177    57.5855596826412
73  1   1   109.151435427561    103.268038055169    114.989749539916    79.0797680695321
74  1   1   44.1915601794505    32.488889575974     47.8871349362105    23.3092880391165
75  1   1   73.7934776486887    101.055099406535    84.1618985567819    103.402981000812
76  1   1   95.0542059478978    97.5911569796704    78.486148113456     68.4867425986232
77  1   1   64.5240726355218    31.671278755378     33.258435447189     40.5905417521354
78  1   1   106.25630590229     57.3504334201694    89.4167040212866    110.270001543683
79  1   1   -32.8285288832798   13.0666964953638    64.1013238102904    10.0353131055683
80  1   1   136.997343492581    143.690139614701    134.005733227978    120.271745852092
81  1   1   70.7343231272323    97.4590508106664    106.172374379448    90.3343680822183
82  1   1   110.209501165981    104.25349711217     40.4199334170602    1.84570821055021
83  1   1   100.124928168325    166.678405906746    157.469180899729    106.005633296499
84  1   1   62.5812451279611    55.6523803940952    47.3468086312141    36.9790454246945
85  1   1   158.704614848065    107.969362033628    56.1774990101832    123.674166267595
86  1   1   56.9197652881344    136.850596044725    83.6842567229687    83.9300268420387
87  1   1   128.125931932392    92.6197201206393    150.508502710328    131.529802017041
88  1   1   64.7593992341357    73.862492217461     65.0649801212256    38.6091230133425
89  1   1   68.9999096964161    80.1939274248903    30.6648554419909    36.9854625032025
90  1   1   98.3010238699883    111.484289666451    84.0643697006305    43.3236053574824
91  1   1   144.016203920245    118.355849401995    150.964556520965    79.3690577232804
92  1   1   56.3672851862174    49.3335857232337    28.0430516312931    -3.75856749795899
93  1   1   50.9904382495696    79.5835591128045    85.1716258269063    89.840247580395
94  1   1   4.79995357692619    63.109484390147     85.3620178819827    145.014718138729
95  1   1   116.342271365265    63.9238823488814    73.6395620422341    98.5908099418167
96  1   1   73.4310676105442    89.8610346746933    59.6218968304398    80.5780124201831
97  1   1   39.0845065963185    67.2066549278885    43.0404190714966    93.8553228463651
98  1   1   84.7341340177175    83.2526354844997    23.6121905738287    107.080712311365
99  1   1   91.3038283312291    135.044667633721    76.792704934174     110.553664837889
100 1   1   79.0049860628834    49.2175049784618    67.1482846117857    55.617484745908
101 1   1   29.5624193037796    .0409501286203806   43.4888184402251    39.8187985904858
102 1   1   51.3765518161258    69.4038526036381    45.9739141565358    50.6597987940666
103 1   1   63.0055365628694    103.322140129569    120.808548140362    105.919544083519
104 1   1   52.8913719708796    70.7470331787717    58.2919624308167    149.453269781413
105 1   1   120.714035605949    105.19250318209     65.8882662961688    88.7091006419313
106 1   1   -7.66766451716536   25.8711209808077    11.6178991397316    15.767943907553
107 1   1   3.72070471161231    62.0273823153584    22.4075847523903    21.7788634487747
108 1   1   51.3172868381968    113.882913281247    90.9005215836042    92.3427665340994
109 1   1   73.5034029649624    62.87236526609      8.81375967033083    -28.4972807134294
110 1   1   99.1011673438447    60.1359669228303    53.8205321646238    96.1744881373656
111 1   1   107.982390062527    135.072911770312    125.382997170895    98.8360994985125
112 1   1   18.3703016279945    53.5680481870766    65.3995855325053    114.196012166461
113 1   2   63.3407691409205    89.4389118123724    81.255769107708     100.393559031196
114 1   2   56.5421572534953    130.6960381422      59.0306960924183    75.4843608239859
115 1   2   53.6415766516234    84.3510275802067    70.3588577776371    7.17774520243648
116 1   2   32.6563157378665    103.863103137957    137.125019714332    137.633650084141
117 1   2   55.6103169017315    64.3121749271763    98.6782025731554    95.2469559040964
118 1   2   18.0644132411083    66.2946440162736    70.1064773432998    37.0526455867338
119 1   2   78.0707752233755    105.514210353922    103.005875726676    74.5737236293205
120 1   2   102.241621141341    101.870735843971    65.2114022842167    79.1628896853278
121 1   2   90.4418459183572    89.1009771794923    109.828940848838    14.1605234087263
122 1   2   168.098799922206    133.913045707145    103.78366545298     78.4568362168323
123 1   2   35.7090570053257    82.1569145373673    89.6599489830234    73.1454809943076
124 1   2   47.9178546235218    104.55609221103     84.063325033245     69.4700774018193
125 1   2   112.097399328943    79.2493293202281    43.9677786050359    33.097338196686
126 1   2   76.6236967002151    108.310865299192    59.2668769569866    85.7884279169812
127 1   2   -9.68798466340358   74.9095212029448    26.2061712938769    -48.5516085044269
128 1   2   112.998248745356    106.008001236265    73.8054153582076    14.1811229738059
129 1   2   108.233164776823    152.044046851601    134.983762387721    61.7054340377302
130 1   2   52.8401153910794    67.4683858534514    47.0885824183792    47.2019614625486
131 1   2   54.0715795536216    80.1460393610179    68.0047798144665    35.7762407840147
132 1   2   14.7567828626484    93.2883767811719    73.3331929932544    29.9865546887769
133 1   2   55.1781270568026    111.21768955155     95.0114679825819    65.3422083272693
134 1   2   4.43500653128196    34.0038153834776    26.8355329322023    -19.248732400278
135 1   2   53.7146461969759    101.924570033764    79.3507104221776    137.799585172542
136 1   2   115.416626940762    98.7063813017698    114.583512474598    47.8066528760494
137 1   2   92.8832002098113    105.095486574613    117.913021787209    114.28506812779
138 1   2   79.1670151767684    137.272559436949    110.671170365682    149.150952988482
139 1   2   41.4916764950108    88.1814608116972    70.7781360402978    56.2502955019036
140 1   2   62.299952297694     79.5442518959365    56.3854107511476    81.6024886897144
141 1   2   69.0703579054148    52.776765534947     84.1625448317378    92.6786544709192
142 1   2   -.749072465661733   37.9509014388929    45.0107418907768    14.1279427398175
143 1   2   62.5452932897767    81.2189303707544    17.1315538180223    4.72972999158627
144 1   2   33.8786649092082    53.8147463106634    37.8014559381097    58.3312339891636
145 2   1   58.4750829402665    97.2248315220446    77.197092547873     65.5159928828053
146 2   1   86.9936228722864    66.1574144764372    109.876241164801    101.050374552729
147 2   1   45.797257668434     -10.6799727646283   16.9239199285245    -2.35156822036691
148 2   1   45.4052424284709    64.0362320451053    -18.9317120769134   58.9156051743804
149 2   1   82.3222552592198    43.7841447176975    48.7467719992006    30.6908078408155
150 2   1   41.4724114870814    17.852908189203     2.65240845835374    17.1640762470276
151 2   1   75.8562984473622    65.278426178487     64.9142539786957    21.511183615897
152 2   1   73.4502794972495    76.9150599813474    106.659511743715    68.1459795314904
153 2   1   30.6986972707736    25.9830967919212    19.2126599722075    40.0176772459464
154 2   1   48.9463104941463    74.3166671883191    94.4199203293464    76.5601739056115
155 2   1   93.664955663169     34.2345681240818    35.1252683477753    51.0690055100367
156 2   1   89.0347714225498    107.917489676586    104.609385598132    72.2295350027298
157 2   1   88.8172895882086    112.088575121553    155.71739850392     82.2519548781208
158 2   1   98.2643566615029    104.198646984885    78.5303387818693    40.3586832708305
159 2   1   140.939818857767    78.0188776879868    81.2063481452701    68.525334485002
160 2   1   86.1936198080317    90.5323375347094    50.990491005716     50.1471294788092
161 2   1   103.870811613831    112.435654424441    58.3101416041746    33.7245926119906
162 2   1   27.2987791945808    53.345632406136     57.9089183269522    76.3952523121297
163 2   1   87.7060341970745    61.291274523674     100.049614808861    26.5530802039375
164 2   1   68.0936102773189    27.546686021281     78.1098864539664    109.117977596292
165 2   1   109.653139087334    108.376652318957    110.5475461516      78.1863689708069
166 2   1   81.8701695708016    79.8883822519127    70.9356570134467    48.0602030880919
167 2   1   90.5334512828109    46.3060080438415    57.7463692516884    72.5177387570704
168 2   1   69.4747837616312    81.0433631539362    84.2928523743015    83.3080622597221
169 2   1   84.3457020439425    34.0958457253984    23.3496696591518    63.8966218043022
170 2   1   85.1367615599717    48.31325458371      71.409002119249     22.7195826358608
171 2   1   6.0519739761238     82.6886765807442    42.9957736674827    48.6043069078819
172 2   1   153.607342017049    94.0689513605759    67.5617502165065    62.5307210431415
173 2   1   113.000428765149    98.5463804067778    47.0973452834747    68.3383901942912
174 2   1   130.149052574106    100.920206253848    126.83942217593     132.801239509274
175 2   1   10.7637884370764    22.7354098644514    58.6681058708439    102.796669810432
176 2   1   46.0462202749716    86.1150070810951    44.3087422654596    47.2714161661316
177 2   1   -27.68834561668     26.0619549334512    -16.3532520219022   22.3775474222391
178 2   1   85.2528610302936    86.632688194587     88.2098310158051    73.9979201031045
179 2   1   68.5946657752244    72.2857403694067    75.8611359593031    92.955988879473
180 2   1   58.7248829125552    74.2281143735229    38.9726075217798    69.6818957036748
181 2   1   114.83344514817     177.249338931554    174.814763104311    134.38841179859
182 2   1   109.399175453506    111.367962077231    -5.55558989059328   28.5262840223053
183 2   1   82.2298452398339    116.012197254927    .228292808400234    75.6485578629752
184 2   1   18.9327474171412    21.6670670950259    16.3945756900044    54.6818026426316
185 2   1   54.2349388585838    16.3669947396341    -1.56399601528626   -18.8892345761952
186 2   1   89.0369674256001    79.6703899767321    36.1189712407708    11.4989067346067
187 2   1   75.8202676457623    65.9635609540475    25.5056447678644    -18.1512392132912
188 2   1   116.339771648292    113.245057242618    86.3115594425365    109.167966173311
189 2   1   117.753925152085    67.7452097303132    4.85479636923036    61.3300645670528
190 2   1   76.3171444782418    51.2881910612134    70.072345943293     32.0402775976214
191 2   1   6.99109934167268    -9.68978382023725   1.3222912300926     3.70565113354709
192 2   1   87.3719506699759    71.0866781094484    77.8383221714908    140.673530786563
193 2   1   61.5221066085255    -12.2201874125806   33.7716972122356    83.5375669493848
194 2   1   59.033619312337     88.3938919099359    88.6469806667526    66.2006388023931
195 2   1   12.7705479386231    52.8599513977407    -8.98178395043158   5.67532437102307
196 2   1   80.4575996457465    80.3674100418745    64.0589629803417    71.3999743886292
197 2   1   169.161756107454    165.448882319084    69.4423743196653    32.3687225071222
198 2   1   96.5770762182269    131.627910387452    166.29019608871     98.559030242817
199 2   1   49.6756456139914    51.1601253391724    95.7385197241244    47.6375896980025
200 2   1   36.9702142332847    52.0308285598544    46.6203485187055    49.9205778435778
201 2   1   31.6712601805128    75.1577635193883    25.5645852430251    41.5771578423282
202 2   1   141.842177028419    79.951615011948     100.275739895567    34.2274701113761
203 2   1   106.278192177332    61.244325122698     22.4441542064441    60.4646195928593
204 2   1   126.846572787508    108.802011494278    97.5118381725256    59.0049523072224
205 2   1   77.2449560227551    134.640458503015    91.3277915052969    35.7743427602639
206 2   1   37.7728733789122    10.2075340055892    8.99376684705592    3.03192118717025
207 2   1   114.8922480495      95.7836293640519    14.3620213702521    45.6468962834769
208 2   1   45.1469870919599    92.8354230186556    19.5880350954832    -7.39316345806174
209 2   1   44.4203645840082    43.6352236864648    -.419805604549687   19.0093669734351
210 2   1   34.4785422004195    67.1335597030613    -7.48295412928773   54.2591610487253
211 2   1   33.7753422990983    67.4665374150396    46.7093420037872    38.8666598509216
212 2   1   36.2533327207531    16.6107822142166    4.9541023098848     -20.8942996647395
213 2   1   42.8875179824501    -2.96980949706499   20.2592671889875    -15.0653299294941
214 2   1   72.7910110012001    14.1832846117514    44.1906517560891    28.8987526058914
215 2   1   37.4981519755605    10.0209572467386    -15.9703049964524   19.8340566832605
216 2   1   55.7991254855275    87.2460127087151    112.514668101071    40.5956062724875
217 2   1   50.0767808073501    36.9527634280403    51.3514405476814    39.1215866903162
218 2   1   35.3884932946901    -16.1159306931375   -25.9845822793937   -28.8618969982463
219 2   1   42.645467117772     71.5512811866725    86.6146088838234    25.4306120300005
220 2   1   84.4571783414763    70.0196700982875    66.0406733064271    91.5530533206067
221 2   1   149.800029292066    119.263221836987    32.7206483746691    44.0768853551691
222 2   1   79.0871305005099    54.933237558365     96.4976033960482    73.9599335371546
223 2   1   49.5234682066419    102.530402155721    86.6150522890923    60.8527172169368
224 2   1   6.68341977650618    30.2420157859321    -16.1975706667556   82.7559857579158
225 2   1   67.5911504383323    -5.55283170793827   -34.1814633855533   -32.384973091358
```

I want to plot a line chart with x-axle being the test scores"pretest", "posttest", "FU_6_month" and "FU_12_month", while the y-axle is the value for the test scores. I also want seperate lines for males and females.

Does anyone know how to do this with the R plot function?

I tried googling it but cannot find anything useful for this type of data, since i want the different test periods as y-axle.

### Thanks.

I did

```
aggregate(anovadata$Pretest ~ anovadata$Group + anovadata$Gender, data = anovadata, mean)
aggregate(anovadata$Posttest ~ anovadata$Group + anovadata$Gender, data = anovadata, mean)
aggregate(anovadata$FU_6_month ~ anovadata$Group + anovadata$Gender, data = anovadata, mean)
aggregate(anovadata$FU_12_month ~ anovadata$Group + anovadata$Gender, data = anovadata, mean)
```

to go get the means for each group. For this i get

```
  anovadata$Group anovadata$Gender anovadata$Pretest
1               1                1              69.9
2               2                1              71.1
3               1                2              62.3
4               2                2              72.0

  anovadata$Group anovadata$Gender anovadata$Posttest
1               1                1               76.7
2               2                1               66.2
3               1                2               90.6
4               2                2               57.6

  anovadata$Group anovadata$Gender anovadata$FU_6_month
1               1                1                 70.1
2               2                1                 52.9
3               1                2                 76.7
4               2                2                 55.0

  anovadata$Group anovadata$Gender anovadata$FU_12_month
1               1                1                  71.9
2               2                1                  49.9
3               1                2                  59.5
4               2                2                  58.3
```

Now i want to make (group 1 gender 1) (group 2 gender 1) (group 1 gender 2) (group 2 gender 2) to be seperate units and the pretest, posttest, FU_6, FU_12 to be different time periods. There should be four in total in the graph.

Does anybody know how to format the aggregates to vectors or matrices without using hardcoding in order to get the lineplot?

Comment: You'll likely need to reshape your data into a long[er] format, with a dummy factor variable of the variables you want to plot, and then a "score" column with the value. You'll also need to do some summary statistics here (means?) unless you want to plot 225 lines. Hadley's packages are really good at this kind of thing; see `dplyr`, `reshape2`, and `tidyr`.

Comment: I need something clarified, do you want a box plot using the 4 categoricals you mentioned (pretest, etc.) ?

Comment: @steveb well yeah it could very well be a box plot, but in my case i need it to be a line plot for the visual effects.

Comment: @alistaire Yeah i only want 4 points, so that sounds correct. I'll look in to it. Thanks!

Comment: To reshape your data you could use the following `d %>% gather(TestType, TestScore, -c(Subject, Group, Gender)) %>% mutate(TestType = factor(TestType))` (assuming your data frame is `d`)